# Image Mapping in a Web Page

Tags: java, html

I am trying to map an image from a local machine and have that image displayed when searched from a different Computer/ IP Address

When trying to use the typical img tag in HTML in my Web Application.
The only situation where an image shows up is when

<> I run My Web application on a different machine from where I want to really run it at.

<> I then map the Network Drive

<> Only shows up on IE.

Comment: Please show your img src url address

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to display a local image on a remote machine without the image being accessible itself on the remote machine? That's not really possible. If for some reason you don't want to use a remote-accessible URI, the best you can do is have your server-side code convert the image into a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), which is basically a base64 encoding of the image file's contents.

Comment: the image is always accessible from a file explorer directory no matter where you are on the network. I want to avoid using that and just display images to my web application. All the permissions are set for anyone on our network to see.

Comment: That's what I mean. If the files exist on the network, in a network location that isn't accessible to the remote user, then the remote user will never be able to see them on the page, unless you convert to a data URL like I suggested. An HTML <img> tag only points the client software to the location of the file, but if that location is inaccessible, then the client will never be able to display it.

If I'm misunderstanding, and the files ARE accessible to the remote machine, you just need to make sure the URL you're using in your tag points to the correct location relative to the remote.